# What are good/best ways to handle jquery namespace collisions?

Tags: jquery

I'm using two jquery plugins.  Both extend jquery with a prototype function `removeTag`.  This causes the second-loaded plugin to work correctly, while the first one does not.

As a quick patch, I renamed the removeTag - and all calls to it - on the second plugin to something else.

Obviously, thats not a good solution.  Upgrades will need to be manually edited, and there could be other namespace collisions that I haven't realized yet.

Can anyone recommend some effective strategies for dealing with this?

The two plugins I am using are:

- jQuery TagIt - http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/
- jQuery TagsInput - https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input

Comment: Two jQuery Libraries, or two jQuery plugins. Big difference there. If it's two jQuery libraries, removeTag isn't the only thing that is conflicting.

Comment: What are the libraries?  And if your namespace is named, can't you call the namespaced version of removeTag (not sure if I'm saying that right).  Or can you give it a name instead of modifying individual methods within the namespace?

Comment: You might get lucky to just invert the calls of your libraries/scripts inside the HTML document and put them at the bottom before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: As a last resort you could use `noConflict`, though that would require you to load jquery twice.  Not to mention using two different aliases for jquery and use the correct one in each call.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  Two plugins.  Will edit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a js file with the code from below:

```
if (jQuery) {
    jQuery.namespace = function(namespace) {
            var names = namespace.split(".");
            var parent = window;
            for (var index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
                    if (!parent[names[index]]) {
                            parent[names[index]] = function() {
                                    throw "Namespace, Cannot instantiate";
                            }
                    }
                    parent = parent[names[index]];
            }
    }
```

}

And on your scripts you can use it like the following:

```
$.namespace("Somejs.MyCustomjs");
```

And later on the Code refer to the full Namespace like:

```
SomeJs.MyCustomjs.myFunc();
```

hope It helps

Edit: I forgot to mention that on the declaration of your js class you netted to use the full namespace

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use `jQuery.sub()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/

This would allow you to create a copy of the `jQuery` object and have the one plugin use the copy.

```
// load jQuery
// load plugin1

var $origJQ = jQuery;
jQuery = jQuery.sub();

// load plugin2

jQuery.plugin2Stuff();
$origJQ.plugin1Stuff();
```

The big drawback though is that you would need to be sure to use the appropriate alias for jQuery when dealing with either plugin.  If at least one of the plugins is just something you call once on load of your page though this may not be a problem.

***EDIT:  Apparently this is deprecated in 1.7 and will be moved to a plugin in 1.8***

Answer (score 0):

After loading in the first plugin, define the function with a different name `$.fn.removeTagsPlugin=$.fn.removeTags` then when you load in the second plugin it can happily overwrite $.fn.removeTags. This has limitations.. If the first plugin uses, internally, removeTags and it won't work if it uses the new plugin's version of removeTags, then this solution won't work.